# VHow to get all data string in rows datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGridview with one column named as "Application". This column has values like "notepad", "cmd", "calc".  How do I get all data from the "application" column and show it in a MessageBox?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this?

```
Dim objMessage As MessageBox
For i = 0 To myDataSet.Items.Count - 1
   objMessage.Text = myDataSet.Rows(i)(columnIndexOfApplication).ToString & vbNewLine
Next
objMessage.Show
```

Comment: No. that's not i need

Comment: So what's your end goal? Do you want all of the application names to appear in one message box? Or all application names and values to appear in one message box? One in each message box?

Comment: yea, i want show data from datagridview to message box. but without use data set. because i don't use database.

Comment: okay, can you extend my functionality above to loop through the columns as well and if you don't have use a database/dataset how is this data grid view populate? You could loop through the items in there as opposed to the dataset.